# Displaying the category of posts but returning empty array

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

Whenever I try to get the category name of a post, it returns an empty "array". I am not proficient with PHP in WordPress, though I have tried many things to get this to work. I have tried using both `get_the_category()` and `the_category(', ')`, but the latter pulls the category names and puts them entirely at the beginning of the function (it looks like it strips the div off of them entirely).

I'd like to display a list of categories that each post belongs to and still keep them within my div ID's. Strangely enough (to me), `get_the_date()` works perfectly fine as is, but `get_the_category()` doesn't.

"Array" in orange should be showing category names separated by commas (ideally):
[image: "Array" in orange should be showing category names separated by commas (ideally)]

This is the code I'm using to get the posts inside of my functions.php file.

```
function ctmblog_posts() { 
 
// Query Arguments
$ctmblog_args = array(
'orderby' => 'date',
'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1',
'cat' => 8,88,87,5 // Use the category id, can also replace with category_name which uses category slug
    //'category_name' => array(SLUG OF FOO CATEGORY),
);

//Loop to display 10 recently updated posts
$ctmblog_loop = new WP_Query( $ctmblog_args );
$counter = 1;
$string .= '<ul><div id="timeline">';
while( $ctmblog_loop->have_posts() && $counter < 10 ) : $ctmblog_loop->the_post();
$string .= '<div id="timeline_event"><span id="timeline_date">'. get_the_date() .'</span> — '.'<span id="timeline_category">' .get_the_category() . '</span>'.' <br><li><a href="' . get_permalink( $ctmblog_loop->post->ID ) . '"> ' .get_the_title( $ctmblog_loop->post->ID ) . '</a></li></div>';
$counter++;
endwhile; 
$string .= '</div></ul>';
return $string;
wp_reset_postdata(); 
} 
 
//add a shortcode
add_shortcode('blog-posts', 'ctmblog_posts');
```

If I could get any pointers, I'd really appreciate it! This is a great learning experience for me. I've searched the web and tried solutions other people have suggested to others, but I think this might be a unique case for me.

Comment: You can't echo arrays (it won't output the contents). Since `get_the_category()` returns an array, if you want it listed separated by commas, you should have a look at [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: it means it's in array format, just simply use an implode function on that, `implode(', ', get_the_category())` like so. it shows like so since you're not supposed to concatenate and string and an array

Comment: I think I might be just a little confused. If I input the implode(', ', get_the_category()) in the string above, I get a critical error on front end. If I insert get_the_category() as an object inside implode, nothing at all gets outputted on the front end. Is there a another way I'm supposed to be using this? I apologize for the unknowingness.

Comment: All I want is the categories in the orange array (under the second $string in the code) to show. There may or may not be more than one category for that particular post.

Answer (score 0):

Let's read the documentation for the get_the_category() function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/

It should work, right? Let's remember that in WordPress each post can have multiple categories - this results in the function returning an array.

Code by wordpress.org user [Stefano](https://profiles.wordpress.org/ragequit/)

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy' );
// now you can view your category in array:
// using var_dump( $categories );
// or you can take all with foreach:
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    echo $category->term_id . ', ' . $category->slug . ', ' . $category->name . '<br />';
}
```